# Switch Angular themes using CSS and Angular material themes

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

every one
I'm working on an angular application in which I need to change themes based on login info. 
I tried using different css pages but that does'nt seem to work as we can use only single css page per component and switching css files looks like impossible for me. I've saved a css file in assets and tried accessing it but its not working.
Is there a way to switch styles.css based on a condition.
Im using angular 4 and typescript if that can help. Or is my approach totally wrong at this and should I be using angular themes given in angular material ? 
The angular material themes are using scss while im using css. So please help!!

Comment: You approach is totally wrong. Which UI Controls are you using? Angular Material?

Comment: One generic way is to add a theme class to your `<body>` and make all theme rules depend on that class. `#main {}` becomes `.red-theme #main{}`, etc.

Comment: My project is big, i cant add classes to all bodies. @Chris G

Comment: Most of the controls are angular material. @Faisal

Comment: @AnkushRanapure In case you misunderstood, you only add a single class to `<body>`. You shouldn't have more than one body in an Angular project.